# Grub2 doesn't show Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I did reinstall UBUNTU 14.04 after having some issues with grub, the problem is that I can't access to my windows 7 anymore as the grub menu shows only Ubuntu partition. 
P.S/
during the reinstallation of ubuntu, I did choose 'erase and reinstall ubuntu .... ' instead of install 'ubuntu alongside ubuntu...'
Windows was always in dual boot with Ubuntu but now I can't access to it.
So please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked, if the Windows partitions are still available. For instance in you file-manager (nautilus) or a partition tool like "disks" (not sure about the name, as I run a German version) or gparted.
If the Windows-partition are gone - sorry, but you lost Win.
If the Windows-partition(s) is/are still on the disk, open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub`. Copy the resulting output to an editor (gedit) and save it. 
Then try a reboot and see if the grub-menu has changed. If not, paste the output from above here.

Comment: When I checked via sudo update-grub2 it didn't show up any Windows 7 (loader) partion like only the Ubuntu partition. I think that Windows was erased too! Now I am trying other stuff. I will do your guides as soon as I finish. thanks

Comment: azed@Kalypso:~$ sudo update-grub2
[sudo] password for azed: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
done

Comment: Sorry - Win is gone. :-( As I am not the data-recover-wizzard I can only suggest, to install gparted and try the data-rescue option in the "partition-menu". (You will then be asked to install a package, of which I can't remember the name. But all needed packages are available in the repositories.)

Comment: Yah, it is gone, tough day, I can't understand how it did happen, I have my stuff on cloud, so not that horrible, but it's sad, Viele Danke Blumchen Blau,